# is maxTotalHeaderLength working as expected?

Tags: haskell, yesod, haskell-warp

Warp has a `settingsMaxTotalHeaderLength` field which by default is 50*1024 : https://hackage.haskell.org/package/warp-3.3.10/docs/src/Network.Wai.Handler.Warp.Settings.html#defaultSettings

I suppose this means 50KB? But, when I try to send a header with ~33KB, server throws bad request:

```
curl -v -w '%{size_request} %{size_upload}' -H @temp.log localhost:8080/v1/version
```

Result:

```
*   Trying 127.0.0.1...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to localhost (127.0.0.1) port 8080 (#0)
> GET /v1/version HTTP/1.1
> Host: localhost:8080
> User-Agent: curl/7.58.0
> Accept: */*
> myheader2: <big header snipped>
> 
* HTTP 1.0, assume close after body
< HTTP/1.0 400 Bad Request
< Date: Wed, 22 Jul 2020 13:15:19 GMT
< Server: Warp/3.3.10
< Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
< 
* Closing connection 0
Bad Request33098 0
```

(note that the request size is 33098)

Same thing works with 32.5KB header file.

My real problem is actually that I need to set `settingsMaxTotalHeaderLength = 160000` to send a header of size ~55KB. Not sure if this is a bug or I am misreading something?

Comment: Just a guess: maybe the 33KB are raw bytes which are encoded using base64 or something similar, making the actual header larger?

Answer (score 2):

Congratulations, it looks like you found a bug in `warp`.  In the definition of [`push`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/warp-3.3.13/docs/src/Network.Wai.Handler.Warp.Request.html#push), there's some double-counting going on.  Near the top, `bsLen` is calculated as the complete length of the header so far, but further down in the `push' Nothing` case that adds newline-free chunks, the length is updated as:

```
len' = len + bsLen
```

when `bsLen` already accounts for `len`.  There are similar problems in the other `push'` cases, where `start` and `end` are offsets into the *complete* header and so shouldn't be added to `len`.

Comment: Thanks. Raised an issue here: https://github.com/yesodweb/wai/issues/807